# Replacing Win 8.1 & Clearing Hardrive

Tags: windows, format

I'd like to completely remove all files from my drive (factory reset, basically) and also uninstall Windows 8.1 from my machine. How would I do this, and if there are multiple ways to do it, what would be the most hassle-free way of doing it?

Comment: are you asking to install ubuntu?

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported/228069#228069

Comment: Do you just want to wipe out a drive or are you also interested in installing another OS after the wipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start installing Ubuntu. *In installation type* choose the last option called *something else*. You can now delete all your partitions and set new ones.
**All your data will be lost!**

Comment: there is also a use entire disk option in the main screen that doesn't require as much effort

Comment: you are right it is easier to choose one of the defined option, but from this more advanced tool you can set partitions as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, so long as you don't need a completely secure erase, you just boot a livecd and open gparted then create a new partition table, also this is a bit off topic here